# Having a non constant current in a constant-current LED driver

Tags: pwm, led-driver, constant-current

I am using the [TPS92511 LED driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92511.pdf) as follows :

[image]

It is not on a PCB but a veroboard with wires so it is not a perfect circuit.

I have chosen R<sub>iadj</sub> to 4.9 kΩ which should give me something around 300 mA according to Table 2:

[image]

I chose R<sub>fs</sub> to 22 kΩ which should give me a switching frequency of 500 kHz according to Table 1:

[image]

The inductor reference is 74477020, the diode reference is GF1D and the LED reference XMLBWT-00-0000-0000U2051. Its forward voltage is 3 V.

I can drive the current with the DIM pin thanks to a PWM obtained by a microcontroller. The PWM frequency is about 20 kHz but I have also tested the circuit with 1 kHz.

I have two problems :

- Whatever value I choose for my PWM, the consumed current is not constant but always oscillating by several mA, which results in a LED that is flickering.
- If I drive the DIM pin high, or set a very high duty cycle, the consumed current is not the 300 mA I am expecting, but around 30 mA.

Is it a normal behavior?
Do you think there is something I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help. :)

[image]

Comment: Just a daft question: what is the inductor resistance? You're running a 3 V LED (white?) on a 5 V supply. 33 Ω in the inductor would cost you 1 V at 30 mA.

Comment: _" capacitor 1 μF"_ - which capacitor? What is the diode (D1) part number, and what are the LED specs? Please show us your actual circuit, and a photo of the board.

Comment: I have updated my problem with all missing information.

Comment: can you measure the DC voltages across LED and the indicator?

Comment: V_iadj = 1.14 V and voltage across LED is 2.4 V